# How to hide email in this jquery form and send blind or carbon copy to another owner?

Tags: jquery, forms

I use this jQuery form but I'm absolutely a newbe in JavaScript.

The script :

```
(function($){
$.fn.extend({
    forms:function(opt){
        if(opt===undefined)
            opt={}
        this.each(function(){
            var th=$(this),
                data=th.data('forms'),
                _={
                    errorCl:'error',
                    emptyCl:'empty',
                    invalidCl:'invalid',
                    successCl:'success',
                    successShow:'4000',
                    mailHandlerURL:'bin/MailHandler.php',
                    ownerEmail:'myemail@mysite.com',
                    stripHTML:true,
                    smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                    targets:'input,textarea',
                    controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                    validate:true,
                    rx:{
                        ".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".state":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
                        ".phone":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".fax":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".message":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'textarea'}
                    },
                    preFu:function(){
                        _.labels.each(function(){
                            var label=$(this),
                                inp=$(_.targets,this),
                                defVal=inp.val(),
                                trueVal=(function(){
                                            var tmp=inp.is('input')?(tmp=label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/),!!tmp&&!!tmp[1]&&tmp[1]):inp.html()
                                            return defVal==''?defVal:tmp
                                        })()
                            trueVal!=defVal
                                &&inp.val(defVal=trueVal||defVal)
                            label.data({defVal:defVal})                             
                            inp
                                .bind('focus',function(){
                                    inp.val()==defVal
                                        &&(inp.val(''),_.hideEmptyFu(label),label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                })
                                .bind('blur',function(){
                                    !inp.val()
                                        ?inp.val(defVal)                                        
                                        :(_.isValid(label)
                                            ?_.showErrorFu(label)
                                            :_.hideErrorFu(label)),
                                        (_.isEmpty(label)
                                            ?_.showEmptyFu(label)
                                            :_.hideEmptyFu(label))
                                })
                                .bind('keyup',function(){
                                    label.hasClass(_.invalidCl)
                                        &&_.isValid(label)
                                            ?_.showErrorFu(label)
                                            :_.hideErrorFu(label)
                                })
                            label.find('.'+_.errorCl+',.'+_.emptyCl).css({display:'block'}).hide()
                        })
                        _.success=$('.'+_.successCl,_.form).hide()
                    },
                    isValid:function(el){
                        var ret=true,
                            empt=_.isEmpty(el)
                        if(empt)
                            ret=false,
                            el.addClass(_.invalidCl)
                        else
                            $.each(_.rx,function(k,d){
                                if(el.is(k))
                                    d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())
                                        ?(el.removeClass(_.invalidCl),ret=false)
                                        :el.addClass(_.invalidCl)
                            })
                        return ret
                    },
                    isEmpty:function(el){
                        var tmp
                        return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                    },
                    validateFu:function(){                          
                        _.labels.each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)                              
                            _.isEmpty(th)
                                ?_.showEmptyFu(th)
                                :_.hideEmptyFu(th)
                            _.isValid(th)
                                ?_.showErrorFu(th)
                                :_.hideErrorFu(th)
                        })
                    },
                    submitFu:function(){
                        _.validateFu()
                        if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                                data:{
                                    name:$('.name input',_.form).val()||'nope',
                                    email:$('.email input',_.form).val()||'nope',
                                    phone:$('.phone input',_.form).val()||'nope',
                                    fax:$('.fax input',_.form).val()||'nope',
                                    state:$('.state input',_.form).val()||'nope',
                                    message:$('.message textarea',_.form).val()||'nope',
                                    owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                    stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                                },
                                success: function(){
                                    _.showFu()
                                }
                            })          
                    },
                    showFu:function(){
                        _.success.slideDown(function(){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                _.success.slideUp()
                                _.form.trigger('reset')
                            },_.successShow)
                        })
                    },
                    controlsFu:function(){
                        $(_.controls,_.form).each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                            th
                                .bind('click',function(){
                                    _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                    return false
                                })
                        })
                    },
                    showErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideDown()
                    },
                    hideErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    showEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideDown()
                        _.hideErrorFu(label)
                    },
                    hideEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    init:function(){
                        _.form=this
                        _.labels=$('label',_.form)

                        _.preFu()

                        _.controlsFu()

                        _.form
                            .bind('submit',function(){
                                if(_.validate)
                                    _.submitFu()
                                else
                                    _.form[0].submit()
                                return false
                            })
                            .bind('reset',function(){
                                _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)                                   
                                _.labels.each(function(){
                                    var th=$(this)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                    _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                                })
                            })
                        _.form.trigger('reset')
                    }
                }
            if(!data)
                (typeof opt=='object'?$.extend(_,opt):_).init.call(th),
                th.data({cScroll:_}),
                data=_
            else
                _=typeof opt=='object'?$.extend(data,opt):data
        })
        return this
    }
})
```

To send a form to a specific owner, i used this script :

```
$(function(){
    $('#contact-form').forms({
        ownerEmail:'myemail@mysite.com'
    })
})
```

But I have two questions :

1. How to send a form to an other owner in blind or carbon copy?
2. How to hide the different owner emails in this jQuery form?
   It seems very easy to show the emailOwner (and so spam his adress
   !).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You'd need to hard-code the `ownerEmail` into your PHP script so that it doesn't fly around the JS.

Comment: I get many errors in jslint with that script...

Comment: Thanks. But can you show me the way to make this hardcoding mail in php ?

Comment: What is jslint ? I'm sorry....

Comment: [JS Lint](http://jslint.com/) is an online JavaScript validator (?), it checks that the pasted JavaScript is valid, or not. If not it gives a report stating where the errors are (or where it thinks the errors are, usually it's pretty accurate (far more so than me)).

Comment: Ok Thanks David ! A way to hardcodding emailOwner in php ?

Answer (score 0):

One commenter suggested to hard-code the email in php. In order to do that, you need to find the php file doing the sending (bin/MailHandler.php from what can be seen from your javascript).

Then find where $_POST['owner_email'] is in that file. Adding an additional email or an email in bcc depends on what is sending your mail. If it is a standard mail function you can add something like this:

```
$headers .= 'Bcc: anotheremail@someaddress.com' . "\r\n";
```

---

If you also want to add it in the javascript
after this line:

```
ownerEmail:'myemail@mysite.com',
```

add:

```
bccEmail:'myemail@mysite.com',
```

and after this line:

```
owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
```

add:

```
bcc_email:_.bccEmail,
```

And again, in your php, where you find the $_POST['ownerEmail'] you can then add $_POST['bccEmail']

Comment: Thank's Very much Scott...but i'm totaly newbee and i would absolutely like that the email adress do not appear in the javascript.

How can i directly hard-codding the ownermail in the mailhandler.php without write this in the js form ?

If i delete the email in the javascript, it seems don't work.

Comment: An other comment say it's very dangerous to use mailHandler.php in this js forms script. Why ?

Comment: Because your file can be accessed from elsewhere then. I recommend always checking the session id to ensure it is the same as the sending page session id (so do session_start on the sending and receiving page, generate a random string, send that random string via javascript as well, and check if the $_SESSION['my_random_string'] matches $_POST/$_GET['my_random_string']

Comment: Sorry and for your first question; look in the php file for $_GET['email'] or $_POST['email'], then just replace that with a fixed string like 'test@test.com'. Nobody can see something hardcoded in php because it is server side, so then it is safely hidden